# Can I retrieve an Outlook room calendar view with the MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using the Graph API we are already successfully retrieving calendar views for a user's calendar (on behalf of the user). Now users would also like to be able to retrieve room calendars. So I tried the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/room1@ourdomain.com/calendarView

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/room1@ourdomain.com/calendarView

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/room1@ourdomain.com/events

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/room1@ourdomain.com/events
```

Unfortunately all of them return a `ErrorServiceUnavailable` error.

App permissions and OAuth2 scopes are set to: `openid email profile offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read.Shared https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All`, so that should not be an issue.

Am I doing something wrong or is this simply not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/room1@ourdomain.com/calendarView is the approach I've used successfully. I had an issue with permissions and gave my app every permission in Azure, and it worked for me. I can't help with which specific permissions it is, but for testing this is how I resolved an issue I had.

Comment: Thanks for Jeremiah. Do you have any thoughts on the comment I posted under Seiya's answer?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something wrong or is this simply not supported?

For your current question: Obviously you did wrong or the Service - side temporary exception. The api is supported.

You should provide the code you have used, and based on the code, we can check what is wrong on your side.

Comment: It is good to know that this should be a working endpoint. And it worked after a bit of waiting. So I continued with development on this, but now it just keeps returning `DelegatedCalendarAccessDenied` errors. App permissions and scopes are still set as mentioned above and I also tried accepting the permissions on behalf of the company. But none of that works. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions) suggests that `Calendars.Read` should be sufficient. Any idea?